# Pandas - Creating multiple default columns from existing column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, array-broadcasting

The follows on from:
[Pandas - creating 2 new columns based on 2 columns and a separate test column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47512396/pandas-creating-2-new-columns-based-on-2-columns-and-a-separate-test-column)

But it's a different question in it's own right.  It should be simpler!

In the referenced question the following one-liner is discussed for data-filling 2 new columns from 2 other columns, and dependent on the value of a third column:

```
df['Buyer ID'], df['Seller ID'] = zip(
    *np.where(df.buy_sell == 'Buy',
             (df.buyer_name,df.seller_name), 
             (df.seller_name,df.buyer_name)).T)
```

This works well - but when I try to simplify this to use fixed scalar values rather than corresponding values in other columns, it doesn't work.

For example, if I only have one possible buyer, John, and one possible Seller, Maggie, then the follow simpler construct should suffice:

```
df['Buyer ID'], df['Seller ID'] = zip(
    *np.where(df.buy_sell == 'Buy',
             ("John","Maggie"), 
             ("Maggie","John")).T)
```

This is failing on the inner np.where() call with:

```
operands could not be broadcast together with shapes
```

I've tried a few variations like wrapping the tuples in zip(), which changes the shape but I still get the error.  I think the problem is that ("John","Maggie") is not returned as the contents of a single column.  The tuple is expanded to mean >1 column?

This link also showed some promise:
[Changing certain values in multiple columns of a pandas DataFrame at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19867734/changing-certain-values-in-multiple-columns-of-a-pandas-dataframe-at-once)

But I think the solution assumes the columns you wish to edit already exist and that you only want the same single value placed in every column.

I can get around the problem by making several passes, but it's not ideal:

```
np.where(df.buy_sell == 'Buy', 'John', 'Maggie')
```

Ideally for each row, I want a single-pass solution extendible to N new columns being filled with different, fixed, default values, but all depending on a single (boolean) value in another column.

Any pointers on what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer from jezrael gives a perfectly good way of doing this.  But to explain why only the first example works in the original question, I found the links below a useful reference:

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html and
https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2015/broadcasting-arrays-in-numpy/

I've applied the references to the case in hand.

To recap:

**First case - this works:**

```
np.where(df.buy_sell == 'Buy',(df.buyer_name,df.seller_name),(df.seller_name,df.buyer_name))
```

**Second case - this doesn't work:**

```
np.where(df.buy_sell == 'Buy',("John","Maggie"), ("Maggie","John"))
```

**Third case - this does work:**

```
np.where(df.buy_sell == 'Buy', 'John', 'Maggie')
```

What (I think!) is happening in the first case is an attempt to broadcast across:

(n,) (n,) (n,) - this is fine because all non-zero dimensions equal

In the second case it is

(n,) (2,) (2,) - this is not OK because non-equal dimensions eg n<>2 - the nature of tuples is that that they are (2,) and clash with the (n,) of the buy_sell.

In the final case it is

(n,) (1,) (1,) - this is the same as the above, however this works because you can stretch a 1 over n, so it doesn't clash.

So to construct something that works for the scalar case we need to alter the tuples:

(n,) (2,) (2,)

To avoid a mismatch we changed it to:

(n,) (2,1) (2,1)

Now this isn't obvious, but what numpy will automagically do to broadcast this is left-pad the (n,) to (1,n), giving us:

(1,n) (2,1) (2,1)

This way there are no mismatched dimensions >1, giving a broadcast object of (2,n) - 2 rows of n columns each.  You can see this by manually applying the `np.broadcast()` to the 3 arrays and calling `shape` on the result.

It's important to understand the difference between (x,) and (x,1) to get how this works.  Basically - (x,) only has 1 dimension, (x,1) has 2 dimensions where the 2nd dimension is restricted to a single value.  See here for details:
[Difference between numpy.array shape (R, 1) and (R,)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22053050/difference-between-numpy-array-shape-r-1-and-r)

So the desired result can be achieved using the construct below:

```
np.where(df.buy_sell == 'Buy', (["John"],["Maggie"]), (["Maggie"],["John"]))
```

The result is then transposed to get n rows of 2 columns, so each row can be passed as parameters into `zip()` to allow multiple assignments.

I'm pretty sure jezrael's solution *effectively* does the same thing, but in this case the buy_sell is given the extra dimension rather than the text outputs - but the same objective is achieved - keeping mismatched >1 dimensions on different axis.

In this case the buy_sell becomes (n,1) so we have

(n,1) (2,) (2,)

Which is left padded to

(n,1) (1,2) (1,2)

Giving a broadcast object of (n,2).

The nice thing about this solution is that no transpose is needed before applying `zip()`.

Answer (score 3):

I think you need expand mask to `2d` array, because need 2 new columns by [`numpy.column_stack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.column_stack.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'buy_sell': ['Buy','Buy','Buy','Sell','Sell']})

m = df.buy_sell == 'Buy'
mask = np.column_stack([m] * 2)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.where(mask, ("John","Maggie"), ("Maggie","John")))
df[['Buyer ID', 'Seller ID']] = df1
print (df)
  buy_sell Buyer ID Seller ID
0      Buy     John    Maggie
1      Buy     John    Maggie
2      Buy     John    Maggie
3     Sell   Maggie      John
4     Sell   Maggie      John
```

EDIT:

After investigate original solution is possible broadcast boolean mask, only need `[:, None]` for `N x 1` array:

```
m = df.buy_sell == 'Buy'
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.where(np.array(m)[:, None], ("John","Maggie"), ("Maggie","John")))
df[['Buyer ID', 'Seller ID']] = df1
print (df)
  buy_sell Buyer ID Seller ID
0      Buy     John    Maggie
1      Buy     John    Maggie
2      Buy     John    Maggie
3     Sell   Maggie      John
4     Sell   Maggie      John
```

Detail:

```
print (np.array(m)[:, None])

[[ True]
 [ True]
 [ True]
 [False]
 [False]]
```

Comment: Thanks - this works and makes sense - the shape of the boolean-index must match the items returned.  But... I'm still not sure why we don't need to stack in the original case i.e. why is (df.buyer_name,df.seller_name) broadcastable, when ("John","Maggie") is not?  Why is .T used to transpose the original answer - I suspect this is part of the magic?

Comment: I investigate it and find better solution with `N, 1` array of boolean. Please check it.